# convert image inputstream to pdf inputstream - Java

Tags: java

How could I convert an Inputstream with an image in it to an Inputstream with that image converted to a pdf in it?

The Inputstream is received with MTOM (WS-project) on the following way:

```
documentIdentification.getFile().getInputStream()
```

Comment: You want pdf with image? Use some pdf generator library. This site not for searching for libraries.

Comment: @talex: It might be a good idea to read the question properly. I'd like to convert an image inputStream to a pdf outputstream. And, I for instance, know that I can use iText to convert an image to PDF (and if I didn't you can always suggest something instead of giving me an answer like that) but I'm stuck with the conversion of the Inputstreams (and I don't want to make files of the InputStream or some byteArray..). Some well builded help would be nicer than some "go away" comment :).

Comment: @GregD What is definitely a good idea is that **you** start by writing your question correctly (*pdf Inputstream*).

Comment: @m0skit0 Alright. Let's all stop bashing on each other. Why isn't the question clear? What's wrong with it? I simply want InputStream1 (an image inputStream) to be converted to InputStream2 (a PDF InputStream) just like my question clearly says.

Comment: @GregD Maybe you can clarify you question. What you have? What you want to achieve? What did you tried already?

Comment: @m0skit0 changed it a bit. I understand that it might not have been clear.

Comment: @talex What's not clear with this question?

Comment: @GregD what did you tried already? Did you tried iText that you mention?

Comment: @talex Ofcourse I looked at iText. And I know how to convert an Image to a pdf. I just want to find a proper way to convert the image INPUTSTREAM to an inputstream with a pdf in it. And I don't want to read the whole image or convert it to a byteArray or something as I already said.

Comment: And to all.. Some ideas may be useful instead of all the comments.. :)

Comment: @GregD I don't see a way to get image from InputStream directly. You have to load it into `byte[]`.

Comment: @talex that's just the exact thing I do not want to do.. hence this SO post

Comment: @GregD You can ask more specific question. Like "how to create iText Image from InputStream without intermediate byte[]". But I think answer is "Impossible". But I don't understand why you have such constraint?

Comment: @talex Because then I will have to read the whole image in my memory. And, if possible, it, to me, doesn't sound like a good idea to load images of 2gig+ into memory.. I kept this question open to see different ideas but it seems that I can't expect that ;)

Comment: You will be loaded in memory anyway because iText will store image in memory before serialization. You can read pdf spec and create document manually. But it is difficult task.

Comment: Jup, but if I already read it in my memory then it will be read 2 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Some ideas may be useful instead of all the comments.. :)

At the risk of stating the obvious, do it in steps.  For example ...

1. Use `avax.imageio.ImageIO` to create a `java.awt.image.BufferedImage`
2. Wrap it as a `com.itextpdf.text.Image`
3. Embed it in a `com.itextpdf.text.PdfDocument`
4. Use `com.itextpdf.text.DocumentWriter` to write the `com.itextpdf.text.PdfDocument` to a `java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream`
5. Get the `byte[]` and wrap it in a `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream`

---

It is theoretically possible to do the transformation without buffering the image in memory, but the existing APIs don't support this.  (You would have a *lot* of coding to do it in Java.  It would be better to look for a standalone image-to-pdf conversion utility.)

You should be able to avoid the intermediate `byte[]` buffer using a `PipedOutputStream` / `PipedInputStream` pair.

Comment: Isn't there a better way for step 5 than using a byteArray? I'd like to avoid that if possible.. But I can't think of any. And thanks for an answer btw ;)

Comment: Possibly you could use a PipedOutputStream / PipedInputStream pair.